# Why can't I say "Yo gusto", I have to say "me gusta"?

Tags: gramática

Is it a special phrase, an exception?
I  m doing duolingo, and i have never seen "yo gusto", only "me gusto"

Answer (score 5):

In Spanish we have no equivalent of the English verb *to like*; instead, we use *gustar*, which is similar to the English *to please* (which can also be translated as *complacer* or other verbs, depending on the context).

Additionally, in Spanish we use the infinitive in many cases where English uses the -ing form. Add to this that with this verb we use to put the subject at the end of the sentence, where the object usually is, and you have everything:

> I like reading --> Reading pleases me --> Me gusta leer
>
> I like fruit --> Fruit pleases me --> Me gusta la fruta

You can use the periphrasis *gustar de* as an equivalent of *to like*, but it sounds affected in Spanish. You are better off using just *gustar*:

> Me gusta leer <--> Gusto de leer

Answer (score 2):

Yo gusto = Someone likes me (It's like "Yo gusto [a alguien]")

Me gusta = I like something

Me gusto = I like myself

Comment: Actually, it is "Yo le gusto [a alguien]"

Comment: But this is not refering to anyone specifically. It's "Yo gusto" in general, you don't say "Yo le gusto" in general, because the "le" does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

La razón es que **gustar** como sinónimo de *agradar*, *caer bien* es un verbo intransitivo. Lo cual quiere quiere decir que no necesita un objeto directo. Entonces, pocas veces verás oraciones como:

> Yo gusto de ti.

En el sentido más estricto, la oración de arriba sería incorrecta. Para poder usar el verbo en una construcción transitiva, se deben anteponer pronombres átonos (*me, nos, te, os, se, le, les*)

> Me gusta ella.
>   Me gustan las naranjas.
>   Me gusta su plática.
>    A los mexicanos nos gusta la comida con picante.

Pero ¡cuidado! no se puede usar *lo, la, los, las.*

Por otro lado,  como sinónimo de *preferir*, *apetecer* o *paladear* es un verbo transitivo.

> ¿Gusta otra bebida?
>   Voy a comer, ¿gustas?
>   ¿Gusta comer ahora? o ¿más tarde?
>   ¿Gustas que te lleve? o ¿caminarás?
>   Gusto un vino tinto

Comment: Truquillo: si al final de una frase le pones dos espacios, hace la función de `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can say both of them. 
If you say "Me gusta leer" or "Yo gusto de leer", you're saying the same thing: "I like to read".

But in spanish, the verb "gustar" doesn't use subject pronouns "Yo", "TÚ", it uses indirect objects "Me", "Le", "Nos".

As a verb, "gustar" is a little more complex than this, but I hope it helps.

Comment: I never listened "Yo gusto de leer". From what country are you?

Comment: I'm from Argentina.

Comment: @Malkev gusto de [inf] is less common, but perfectly correct (I speak Peninsular Spanish). That said, this answer isn't entirely correct. *Gustar* can use subject pronouns, although as in general in Spanish, they aren't required unless used emphatically or contrastively: *me gustas tú, ¿te gusto yo?*. It does, interestingly, require the indirect pronouns when used in the more common *me/te/etc gusta* structure which isn't as common for verbs (*(le)* dije algo a María* but *le gusta algo a María*)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in itself, "Yo gusto" is incomplete; you would have to use it as in the following sentence, taken from [La esclava de su galán: comedia en tres actos de Lope de Vega](https://books.google.com/books?id=f-UxAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%22Yo%20gusto%20mucho%20de%20t%C3%AD%22&source=bl&ots=QqMgu4f0Xb&sig=bxiRV49KlYF9u0ZO0W_kS0jCAMo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6h_ivpJzPAhWL14MKHeCnD5UQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Yo%20gusto%20mucho%20de%20t%C3%AD%22&f=false):

> "Yo gusto mucho de tí."

In contrast, "Me gusta" is a complete sentence.

Comment: En defensa de @franfernandz.

Comment: Yeah, recommend Spanish from 500 years ago who is not usually used to someone learning it. Nice.

Comment: Here is an example published in 2006: [Yo gusto de coliflores](https://books.google.com/books?id=eIoagMJPYWwC&pg=RA1-PA90&lpg=RA1-PA90&dq=%22yo+gusto+de%22&source=bl&ots=0N7kN9ROsB&sig=Rfa2Jl4685sljhoo0LTeaS3Mig8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjsvTBv53PAhWL2YMKHdw2B0wQ6AEIZDAM#v=onepage&q=%22yo%20gusto%20de%22&f=false)

Comment: Montaigne and Shakespeare are from 2006? Anyway, as I say, it's not usually used in the present and even less outside poetry.

Comment: The book was published in 2006.  The fact that you, or I for that matter, do not use an expression commonly does not mean it is incorrect grammar.  However, in your answer "yo gusto" was incorrect and I suggest you edit your answer.

Comment: No, the question is for "Yo gusto" no "Yo gusto de...". And yes, the book is published in 2006, but maybe the title gives you a clue about who write the texts. I can publish a book from 1400 if I want and that not gonna make Chaucer revive. If you didn't like my answer, add you another, this is a community, we are not fighting, we are on the same team.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45643/discussion-between-david-and-malkev).